# How to run docusign JWT

Tags: jwt, docusignapi

I downloaded code-examples-java from quickstart in developers.docusign.com.
When I run the project in STS (SpringToolSite) it lets me to login with JWT, but when I create the project as a war file and run it in tomcat(localhost) it does not let me to login with JWT, it just reloads the same page for choosing the authentication type.

I would like for example to go in eg011 page from localhost without need to login first.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check you didn't fell on a similar issue described here: [DocuSign war deployment in java return 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75683636/docusign-war-deployment-in-java-return-404-not-found)
And where the solution was to: "all we did was extend the App.java class to Servlet SpringBootServletInitializer, and added the tomcat dependency in the pom and it worked"
In case the problem persisted, thanks to open a case on the Docusign Support Center please.

Comment: It don't help me, because I am able to run it as a war file in localhost(tomcat), the problem is when I try to choose to login with JWT, it only gets me in the same page for choosing the authentication type.
When I run it from my IDE (springtoolsite) i can login with JWT.